# build Apk on physical device crash android studio flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, build, crash

When I build my app on emulator (android 11 API 30)  it's working fine,
but when I try building on my old physical device (Android Kitkat API 19) It crash.

Edit : Yes developer options is enabled

But when I run terminal `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` or `flutter run --release` it works
I can run it on physical device

I know I need armeabi v7 to make it work on my phone but its annoying to have to use console everytime I want to build

Unless I'm doing it wrong how do I build this on my IDE

Edit 2 :
Here's my appbuild

```
minSdkVersion 19

buildTypes {
customDebugType {
        debuggable true
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
    staging {
        initWith debug
        applicationIdSuffix ".debugStaging"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom run configuration to execute any shell script.

To do so in Android Studio, go to Run -> Edit Configurations...

[image: Android Studio Edit Configurations... option]

In the configurations window, click the + icon and select Shell Script

[image: Configuration option menu in Android Studio]

Once it's added, you can give the script a name and for the "Script Path" select the flutter executable (This can be found inside the flutter SDK folder specifically inside a bin folder). For the "Script options", you can add the options you would like Flutter to execute such as `build apk --split-per-abi` or `run --release`

[image: Android Studio Shell Script Options]

At this point, you can click apply and ok. You should now see this custom runner in the drop down menu where you can run different tasks.

[image: Android Studio run option drop down]

Comment: Thanks this is a quick workaround, also do I need to include anything on "Interpreter path " ?

Comment: @IshakBenaissa No you can leave that blank